# how to make css hover just only in a bullet area

Tags: html, css

I have a problem like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/junaserbaserbi/k2uepv26/2/)). Why does the hover of the absolute position is not only the bullet area? It cause I can't click the button, because of it covered by that absolute position. I want that tooltip shows only just when mouse over on the top of the bullet area not outside. Please help me, tq.

css:

```
.badgeP {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    padding-bottom: -10px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.badgeP > li{
    display: inline-block;          
}
li.badgeP1:before{
    content: "\25cf\00a0";
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 100%;            
    position: relative; 
    left: 6px;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
li.badgeP1:before {
    color: orange;
}
.badgeP1:hover .ttbadgeP1{
    opacity:1;
}
.badgeP1{
    position: relative;
}

.ttbadgeP1{
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 90%;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 40px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 3px;
    left: -18px;
    top: 17px;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:  opacity 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition:  opacity 0.5s;
    transition:  opacity 0.5s;
}
.ttbadgeP1-text:before{
    content: '';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
    left: 17px;
    top: -8px;
}
.ttbadgeP1-text{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

html:

```
<ul class='badgeP'>
    <li class='badgeP1'>
      <span class='ttbadgeP1'><span class='ttbadgeP1-text'>reputasi klik</span></span> 556
    </li>
</ul>
<br>
. <input type='button' value='muke'></input>
```

Comment: thanks @morels for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get that badge (.ttbadgeP1) out ouf your way first, using visibility:

```
.ttbadgeP1{visibility:hidden;}
```

then show it only on hover:

```
.badgeP1:hover .ttbadgeP1{visibility:visible;}
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k2uepv26/3/

note that you can't just use the `display` property instead of `visibility`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3331353/176140) for details

Comment: Great. I accept your answer and It works then. Thanks.

Comment: Schellmax, please help me again in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system)

Answer (score 1):

Please change the width of .ttbadgeP1

```
.ttbadgeP1 {
  width: 72px;
}
```

Comment: Jiiiah, si akang Adi, pinter juga cara ngelesnya nih. Keren sih solusinya. Tapi hapunten kang, ane prefer jawabannya schellmax kang. Tapi ane +1 kang, tenang aja kang.

Comment: Kang Adi, bantuin lagi dong [disini](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system)